# views/layouts/application.html.erb one page excemption

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I would like to have one page which will not display the bootstrap navigation bar, which I have in the application.html.erb. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend `MarsAtomic`'s answer, you'll need to look at the [`layout`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Layouts/ClassMethods/layout) method:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   layout false #-> this will not render any layout each time an action inside this controller is invoked
end

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def index
      layout false #-> no layout only for "application#index"
   end

   def show
      render :new, layout: "test" #-> renders "new" action with "test" layout
   end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to still apply bootstrap on that page? Because when I do this, yes it does not apply the layout but it also ignores the bootstrap.

Comment: Don't worry, it's sorted.

Comment: Nice - how did you fix it?

Comment: created a blank layout inside of the view. Not sure if it is the 'proper' way to do it but it does the job. By creating a <head></head> section with the links to external css files I managed to connect to bootstrap while the controller still renders false layout.

Comment: hmm okay. I think there would be a better way, but if you're happy with it then that's cool too!!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of argument, let's say you want to suppress your bootstrap navigation bar on the `index` action for a model called `Foo`.

In your `foos_controller.rb`, you'd add the following to the `index` method:

```
render :layout => false
```

Your `index` view will be rendered without the contents of `application.html.erb`.

If there are some parts of `application.html.erb aside` from the bootstrap nav bar that you wish to include, you have to edit `index.html.erb` to include them.